# Force the approval process for a single edit of mine

Tags: discussion, edits, editing-help

I have enough rep that my edits are automatically approved, but
sometimes I restrict myself from an edit that, in my opinion, is
beneficial.

I'm speaking of questions' titles. Titles can be too generic, or
plainly misleading! but I'm afraid that editing a title (I'm not
speaking of correcting a spelling mistake, I mean CHANGING the title
to better reflect the question content, or to help searches) could be
inappropriate in the eyes of the OP or the community.

In such cases what I would like to do is, submit my edit into the
regular approval queue so that my idea of betterment is scrutinized
before it takes effect.

Is it possible now?  or could it be implemented in the future?

---

I understand that there are different mechanisms that can remediate a
bad edit, but all of these are ex-post.

Comment: It's not possible to send an edit into the queue once you have 2k rep.

Comment: The OP and the community and roll back you edit if they fell it deviates from what it should be.  IMHO making the title clearer/expressing the problem better is a good thing and should be done.  This is double true if it makes finding it with a search engine easier.

Comment: @davidism Chat rooms...  Just a matter of personal taste but for me it's no, but I understand that others may find your suggestion the simplest and most appropriate (hence I clicked its up-arrow...).

Comment: Can't anyone edit posts, even anonymous users? If so, you can just logout or open a new incognito window and make the edit there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to force an edit through review after you gain full edit privileges. I also doubt it would be implemented in the future as you really looking for review from people with non-trivial knowledge on the subject - which edit review queue does not provide.

Note that titles need to reflect problem *and* help others to identify matching answers. Sometimes "broken" title is actually what makes problem identifiable: i.e. some cryptic (but unique) compiler error is much better title than title with real problem like "missing comma caused error". The higher popularity of the question more worried I'd be editing the title.

Your options (as alternatives to edit and live happily there after):

- do nothing - if you don't think your edit significantly improves title and does not hurt ability to search for the question than leaving title as-is should be fine.
- ask first on meta. I would do it only for very high traffic question (at least 1K+ views/50+ votes). Expect "answers" to be just in form up/down votes on the post so (if you can't handle downvotes - skip that option)
- edit post instead to clarify meaning (maybe even "question is {original q} or can be phrased like {your desired title}")
- edit title and ask in one of chat rooms, likely there is at least language-specific chat room.
- add comment to OP asking to change title ("Consider to change title to {your suggestion} because it will help {whatever your reasoning is}").